# Use validators in valuechanges with dynamic Reactive forms to performe tests

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have for example one control which is a group of radio buttons.

- choice1
- choice2
- choice3

if choice1 or choice2 are checked AND it's not compatible with a field I have in my component TS then the custom validator should reject the user action and comeback to the previous state and value.

component.ts

```
  toFormGroup(properties: PropertyBase<string>[]): FormGroup {
    const group: any = {};
    properties.forEach(property => {
      const validators = this.service.getValidatorsByProperty(property);
      if (property.required) validators.push(Validators.required);
      const formControl = group[property.key] = new FormControl(
        {
          property.value,
          disabled: property.disabled || false
        }
      );
      formControl
      .valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(/** comp destroyed */))
      .subscribe(val => {
        formControl.setValidators(validators);
        // if validators fail then I reset formControl to its previous state and value
        // else submit the changes
        submit(val);
      });
    });
    return new FormGroup(group);
  }
```

Validator example

```
export function myValidator(
  theFieldINeedForMyCondition: any
): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    let forbidden = false;
    if (theFieldINeedForMyCondition)
      forbidden = true;
    return forbidden ? { forbiddenValue: { value: control.value } } : null;
  };
// Maybe reset state and value directly here ?
}
```

So the question is : can I for example set back the selection on choice3 if I checked choice2 ?